# How to detect color panel's color change in Mac Catalyst app?

Tags: ios, macos, mac-catalyst, nscolorpanel

In Mac Catalyst, there is a default toolbar item that shows a color panel.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstoolbaritem/identifier/1531463-showcolors

It shows up just fine, but I can't find a way to detect a color change from this color panel. Does anyone know how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the toolbar item is clicked, an instance of `NSColorPanel` is shown. The selected color can be accessed from `NSColorPanel.color`, but we don't have a reference to the shown panel. Even the class `NSColorPanel` isn't visible to Mac Catalyst apps.

Fortunately, there is a [notification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscolorpanelcolordidchangenotification?language=objc) that is posted when a color is selected in a color panel. So, all we need is to observe that notification to get a reference to the `NSColorPanel` instance, and then access its `color` property:

```swift
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .init("NSColorPanelColorDidChangeNotification"), object: nil, queue: nil) { notification in
    let color = (notification.object as? NSObject)?.value(forKey: "color") as? UIColor
    print("Color changed", color)
}
```

Comment: That's work, but not sure it is gonna pass the review or not.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will. You're not accessing any private API here. All is documented.

Comment: @Hejazi can you please provide objective-c code?

Comment: @YogendraPatel Well, this is homework for you :) Seriously though, it's basic event listening using `NSNotificationCenter`. You can easily do it yourself.